# Azure Functions Pricing for Multiple Apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I know that Azure Functions is free up to 1M executions and 400,000 GB-s every month.

Is this per function app per month?

If I have 3 function apps, does each get this allowance free each month?

Comment: Use this, it looks more intuitive: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=functions#functionse9e50b69-a40b-49cf-acac-83786868417a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [`pricing page`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/), this limit is combined for all Function Apps in an Azure Subscription.

> Azure Functions consumption plan is billed based on per-second
>   resource consumption and executions. **Consumption plan pricing includes
>   a monthly free grant of 1 million requests and 400,000 GB-s of
>   resource consumption per month per subscription in pay-as-you-go
>   pricing *across all function apps in that subscription***. Azure Functions
>   Premium plan provides enhanced performance and is billed on a per
>   second basis based on the number of vCPU-s and GB-s your Premium
>   Functions consume. Customers can also run Functions within their App
>   Service plan at regular App Service plan rates.